# Representations of SU(N)

Tags: representation-theory, mathematical-physics

I'm reading [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104178138) by Wittten.  On page 374, 2nd paragraph, he states that 
$$
R\otimes R =\oplus_{i=1}^sE_i
$$ where $E_i$ is a distinct irreducible representation. He then gives a special case for the group $SU(N)$ and states that if $R$ is the defining $N$ dimensional representation then $s=2$.  It isn't clear to me why $s=2$; perhaps if someone could tell me what the 'defining' $N$ dimensional representation was I could work out an example.

Comment: Well, $SU(n)$ is a group of $n\times n$ matrices, and we apply those matrices to $\Bbb C^n$...

Comment: @anon Thanks.  I don't think my question was super clear so for the sake of anyone reading this the answer is defining refers to the trace 0 property.

Comment: "Defining" refers to the fact that the set of vectors that the elements of $SU(n)$ act on is built into the very definition of $SU(n)$ (since the elements are $n\times n$ matrices). We would also use the term "defining representation" for unitary, special linear, general linear - any matrix group. (And by "trace zero" I assume you're referring to ${\frak su}(n)$, whereas $SU(n)$ is defined by having determinant $1$. Interchanging lie algebras and Lie groups seems common in physics.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $SU(N)$ has a representation $R$ on $\Bbb C^n$ where a matrix $M$ acts on a vector $v$ by multiplication giving $Mv$.
I call $R$ the *tautological representation*.
As our group is $SU(N)$ the representation $R\otimes R$ is isomorphic to the set
of $N$-by-$N$ matrices where $SU(N)$ acts by conjugation $(M,A)\mapsto
MAM^{-1}$. This breaks up as the direct sum of two irreducible representations: the scalar matrices, and the trace-zero matrices.

Comment: Thanks, so by defining he's referring to the trace=0 property.  It's clear now.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually my last comment didn't make much sense.  Let me try again to test my understanding.  In your map $(M,A)\mapsto MAM^{-1}$ is $A$ the outer product of two vectors in $C^n$?  I.e. $M(v_1\otimes v_2)= Mv_1\otimes Mv_2=M(v_1v_2^T)M^{-1}\otimes 1$